# SQL: number of rows with specific value's (dynamic)

Tags: sql-server, count

Hard to explain problem here :)

I need to get a new column I have the amount of lines
F.E. "RIT-17000263-T: 1" would have an extra column "Total Sequences": '9'
"RIT-17000264-T: 1" would be "Total Sequences": '2'

Any help is welcome!:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(R.[Trip No_],'-', CONCAT('T: ', LEFT(R.[Partial trip Line No_],1))) AS 'TRIP',
    R.[File] AS 'FILE',
    R.[Sequence No_] AS 'SEQUENCE IN PTRIP'
FROM            
    [Route] AS R
WHERE           
    (R.[Trip No_] = 'RIT-17000263' 
     OR R.[Trip No_] = 'RIT-17000264')
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT(R.[Trip No_], '-', CONCAT('T: ', LEFT(R.[Partial trip Line No_],1))), 
    R.[File], R.[Sequence No_]
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry!, SQL-SERVER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps wrap it in a CTE...

```
with cte as(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    CONCAT(R.[Trip No_],'-', CONCAT('T: ', LEFT(R.[Partial trip Line No_],1))) AS 'TRIP',
    R.[File] AS 'FILE',
    R.[Sequence No_] AS 'SEQUENCE IN TRIP'
FROM            
    [Route] AS R
WHERE           
    (R.[Trip No_] = 'RIT-17000263' 
     OR R.[Trip No_] = 'RIT-17000264')
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT(R.[Trip No_], '-', CONCAT('T: ', LEFT(R.[Partial trip Line No_],1))), 
    R.[File], R.[Sequence No_])

select
    c.TRIP,
    c.[FILE],
    c.[SEQUENCE IN TRIP],
    c2.CT as [Total Sequences]
from 
    cte c
    join (select TRIP, count(TRIP) as CT from cte group by TRIP) c2 on c2.TRIP = c.TRIP
```

Comment: Approach looks great!, but i'm getting an error on the join? 

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'c2'

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it @Gregory

Comment: Cheers Mate! @Gregory